# Python Pivot Table Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, pivot, data-analysis

I'm new to pandas and Python. I have a pivot table like:

```
grp3 = DataFrame(hrsub.pivot_table('left',index = 'sales',columns = 'sat_levels', aggfunc = 'count'))
```

output:

```
sat_levels  
    low high

IT  199 74

RandD   85  36

accounting  161 43

hr  159 56

management  66  25

marketing   149 54

product_mng 129 69

sales   727 287

support 383 172

technical   492 205
```

I want to take the ratio of two columns via

```
hrsub['low']/hrsub['high']
```

But it errors out saying that data should be 1-dimensional. What should I be doing instead?

Comment: Your new DataFrame variable is `grp3` and not `hrsub`

Comment: Yeah sorry I meant grp3['low']/ grp3['high'] throws an error

Comment: You shouldn't wrap the result of the `pivot_table` in the `DataFrame` function. Just save it directly to `grp3`.

Answer (score -2):

Python Pandas Pivot table:

```
 pandas.pivot_table(data, values=None, index=None, columns=None, aggfunc='mean',
                       fill_value=None, margins=False, dropna=True, margins_name='All')
```

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.pivot_table.html